# Shine effect html animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a problem with the animation, I would like the transition to happen only once, or not be visible on both sides. The text stops in the middle or on the sides, trying to change background-position it also did not work

```
 <div class="content">
        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
```

```
 .content p{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.content p{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white, hsl(0, 0%, 0%) 10%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    animation: shine 2s infinite linear;

}

@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    background-position: 0;
  }
  60% {
    background-position: 600px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 600px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Reza's code, I was able to modify slightly ".content div" by changing "animation:shine 2.5s infinite;" to "animation:shine 2.5s 1;", and "left" to "-100px".

```css
  .content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: -100px;
  width: 30%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, transparent 50%);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: shine 2.5s 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    left: -10%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 110%
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/1gdx706t/1/